How does ConvLSTM1D works for an input with the row dim=1?
I want to do timeseries forecasting using ConvLSTM1D. My dataset has only one variable (electricity price). I want to forecast the electricity price of future using only the past 72 hours of prices. Right now the input shape is as follows:
model.add(Input((72, 1, 1)))
Considering the TensorFlow documentation the input shape of the ConvLSTM1D is as follows:
4D tensor with shape: (samples, time, channels, rows).
In this case the time=72, channels=1, and rows=1. Now with kernel_size=2, why doesn't tensorflow throw and error saying kernel_size>input row dimension? What is the ConvLSTM1D is convolving on in this case?

TensorFlow doesn't throw an error for a kernel size and kernel size of 2 is valid, because ConvLSTM1D  is convolving over the time axis, not over the rows  dimension (which is 1). The kernel doesn't need to interact with the rows dimension because there's only 1 value per time step.

You mean that even if the row>1, the ConvLSTM1D would not convolve on the row dim?

In this case, where rows > 1, the kernel is applied independently to each row at every time step, moving across the time dimension.
